# What's the best practice for whitelisting users when using OAuth via Facebook?

Tags: facebook, oauth

Facebook provides an [OAuth authentication system](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/) for third-party apps but they appear to not provide any fine-grained user management capabilities.

This seems like a security problem.  I need to be able to:

1. Disable delete unused accounts
2. Disable or delete abusive users
3. White list users for early access to a new app.

But AFAICT FB provides no tool to do this.

I can probably hook of of the OAuth ID and put an entry in my database for the first two requirements, but I can't figure out how to white list Facebook users.

Google is unhelpful because all the results are about let users manage applications their user account is attached to, and nothing about allowing apps to manage what user accounts they are attached to...

Comment: Why not filter on some identifiable attribute like email? ie. Have the user sign in with Facebook to authenticate, then ask Facebook for their email. If it matches the one in your DB, they have access (for alpha/beta access). If the email's on a black list, kick them out.

edit: I just want to say, it's probably not a good idea to store user's emails, so maybe grabbing the user's ID would suffice (but you'd need to be able to get their Facebook ID *before* they've signed in).

Comment: _"Facebook provides an OAuth authentication system for third-party apps but they appear to not provide any fine-grained user management capabilities."_ - congratulations, you have just discovered what the term _authentication_ means. It is a way to confirm, _"yes, that person is who they say they are_" (in this case, a specific Facebook user) - no more, no less. If _you_ need any kind of _"fine-grained user management capabilities"_ in _your_ system, then _you_ need to implement them.

Answer (score 0):

Usually is a bad idea to delete or disable unused accounts, because maybe user was inactive for a long time, this doesn't mean the user deleted or disabled his account.

On the other hand, you can't avoid malicious users join your app via facebook authentication. What you can do is to detect suspicious activities with your own implementation (after Facebook accept them to join your app), and suspend, block or disable those accounts on the server (blacklisting them), after the user has joined client-side and sent the required access-token (optionally request the ID) trying to be accepted by the server.

Whitelisting users may depend on the requirements of your application, you can check profiles data and reject those that doesn't provide the requirements that your app needs (remember to ask the user for the fields that your app requires, like public profile, pictures, etc; these must be accepted by the user before signing in).

Comment: What I really want is an invite only list on FB, e.g. exactly like a friend's list...except for on the app page.  I thought there was a way to do that, but can't find the docs.  Otherwise... can't see how to make whitelisting work cleanly.

Comment: Facebook login simply provides another way to login into an application (same as email login), and it serves you the data that you require of the user, without the user having to enter names or email, or having to verify email address, etc. Also the FB API helps you to invite friends to the app, or make posts on behalf of the user. If you need a complex system, you have to apply your own login. I don't understand what do you mean with "friend list". Maybe this [friend list](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/friend-list/)?

Comment: a friend list for an app would be those invited to the app.   There are private invite-only forums on FB as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you white list users for an app on Facebook:

1. Keep the app  in Development mode
2. Add users from your friend network in the [Testers role](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/security/)
3. When you are comfortable, open your application to the world.

AFAICT you cannot white list when your app is published, but that's the point of publishing.  Also the whitelist is not a request-grant method, it's invite only.

The other requirement to delete or disable users you must handle yourself in your database.  You would tie the user's status to the FB's unique ID.

Comment: Be aware, if you are using passport-facebook and are testing with passport-mocked for testing you will run into this issue when managing disabled users:  https://github.com/shake-apps/passport-mocked/issues/16